# color and change line type in a ggplot by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe so far as follows:

```
  N Method1-Simulation Method1-Analytical Method2-Simulation Method3-Analytical
1 2              0.094          0.1831891              0.158          0.2789826
2 3              0.236          0.2856285              0.434          0.4670031
3 4              0.349          0.3740548              0.568          0.6097311
4 5              0.450          0.4525999              0.682          0.7174169
5 6              0.506          0.5228121              0.781          0.7976934
6 7              0.585          0.5854665              0.851          0.8566850
```

It will grow to accommodate more methods. I want to make a ggplot where each method has it's own color and the analytical method is a solid line while the simulation method is a broken line.

I have everything but the broken line as follows:

```
longPowerCurve <- melt(powerCurve, id = "N")
colnames(longPowerCurve)[2] <- "Method"

ggplot(data=longPowerCurve,aes(x=N, y=value, colour=Method)) + geom_line() +ylab("Power") +ggtitle("Power levels for various N and distributions")+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

Is there a way I can automate this so that if I have 5, 6,7,8, etc methods, it all still works?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want to split the method.type column.  In that way, you can use the two factors separately for your plot.  To have the dotted line, you would use the `linetype` parameter.

```
groups <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(longPowerCurve$Method),'.',fixed=TRUE)))
colnames(groups) <- c("Method", "Type")
longPowerCurve$Method <- groups$Method
longPowerCurve$Type <- groups$Type

ggplot(data=longPowerCurve,aes(x=N, y=value, colour=Method, linetype=Type)) + 
  geom_line() +
  ylab("Power") +
  ggtitle("Power levels for various N and distributions")+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely closer but what happened to the dotted blue line and the whole green line?

Comment: @user1357015, the data you provided only had analytical for method 3 and simulation for method 2, hence only the solid blue and dotted green.  If the data contained them it would have those lines.

Comment: @cdterman: woops -you're right. Sorry! I'll mark this as complete